# How to displayed fixed menus, extracted from the main menu?

Tags: theming, routes

I am using a Bartik subtheme, and would like to split the main menu into 4 smaller menus, and display them in the four footer columns, side by side. I would like the same menus to be displayed on all pages.

How would I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you go to `admin/structure/menu/add` and add four menus (Footer 1, Footer 2 ...), four blocks of the same name will also be created. Then go to your Main Menu and move the links into the new menus you have created.

Place these blocks where you want them at `admin/structure/block` and modify your stylesheets to make sure they display the way you want.

Comment: Thank you @Triskelion
If I then update the Main Menu items, will the changes also be reflected in my newly created menus?

Comment: No. You move or copy the menu items into the new menus, and maintain the individual menus separately.

Comment: Thanks again @Triskelion
Is there any way of only maintening one menu set? Also, how would I go about copying/moving the menu items? Do you mean add new links?

Comment: Go to admin/structure/menu/manage/main-menu, edit the link you wish to move, and under 'Parent Link' choose the new menu. If you have a hierarchy of menu items, moving the parent will move the entire tree.